# What are the different arguments passed to tar command?

Tags: tar

What is the purpose of `-xvzf` arguments when we untar any tarBall file and what are the other arguments passed over the command?

I found it mentioned in many books but can't find anything.

Comment: This question really fails the minimum effort and usefulness test.  We don't need a bunch of different Q: what are the command line options for `X`, A: <man page for X>.

Comment: Did you google "What is the purpose of -xvzf arguments when we untar any tarBall file"?

Comment: i googled it! and i found this question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just type `man tar` in the terminal for the `tar` command manual.
You can also view it online at http://man.cx/tar or at http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/tar1.html (Thanks to @Rinzwind)

The meaning of -xvzf is

```
-x --extract = extract files from an archive
-v, --verbose = verbosely list files processed
-z, --gzip = gzipped files eg. for tar.gz packages
-f, --file ARCHIVE = use archive file or device ARCHIVE
```

Comment: Here is another one: http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/tar1.html

Comment: If you are going to link to online man pages, prefer Ubuntu's: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/tar.1 - you can pick the version as well, so that you and everyone else are on the same page.

Answer (score 6):

From the `tar` man page -

```
-x, --extract, --get

      extract files from an archive

-v, --verbose

      verbosely list files processed

-z, --gzip, --gunzip, --ungzip

      filter the archive through gzip

-f, --file [HOSTNAME:]F

      use archive file or device F (default "-", meaning stdin/stdout)
```

Type `man tar` in a Terminal to access the man page for tar.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by previous answers the man page will give you a detailed answer to your question.

Additionally, you can access command information through the `help` argument in a slightly more concise format than the man page gives.  By typing `tar --help` you can lookup the x, v, z, and f arguments.

Answer (score 2):

If you are at a linux terminal you can type 'man tar' for the manual page for tar which lists all the command line switches for tar and what they do. You can also google man tar for the same page.
(the man pages are great for learning about commands on linux)

-xvzf means :-

x extract - extract the files from the archive

v verbose - list all files as they are processed

z uncompress - in this case, or compress if creating a tar

f use a file (The file you are uncompressing)

....but there are lots more switches for tar. Take a look.